# Is the question "If you didn't break the vase, who did?" a conditional sentence?

Tags: questions, past-tense, conditionals

My problem is that I was taught (I think wrongly) that whenever a conditional sentence refers to past, there should be past perfect tense in the if clause, as in example 1.

Example 1:

> If you hadn't broken the vase, you wouldn't have angered your parents.
>   [He broke the vase, no doubt about it.]

But is example 2 still a conditional sentence, and is it correct?

Example 2:

> If you didn't break the vase, who did?

We're still referring to past, but we don't really know whether he did it or not.

Is this an example of a conditional sentence? Why or why not? How do I recognize a "past" conditional sentence?

Comment: Please start by reading [this comment exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240554/first-second-and-third-conditional#comment519342_240554). Then clarify your question by using the "edit" link. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example 2 means

> If you didn't break the vase, then I ask you who did?

The condition is on the speech act of questioning.  If you *did* break the vase, than I needn't ask.  Compare:

> If you don't mind my asking, who broke the vase?

The condition here is also a condition on my asking the question.  This is a general formula -- to be polite, you mention conditions that might make it inappropriate to ask a question.